# How to click on <option> value inside <select> Python

Tags: python, html, selenium, select

I try to click on a certaion option using the code:

```
    countries_dropdown = self.browser.find_element_by_class_name('countryBR')

    dropdown = countries_dropdown.find_element_by_id('ControlGroupContact_ContactInputView_DropDownListCountry')
    self.browser.execute_script("arguments[0].classList.remove('jqTransformHidden');", dropdown)
    country_dropdown = Select(countries_dropdown.find_element_by_id('ControlGroupContact_ContactInputView_DropDownListCountry'))

    country_dropdown.select_by_value(payer_details.country_code.upper())
```

It seems like clicking but than when I try to click on the states the list is empty and the country dropdown seems open

Comment: Is it a public site and you can share the link to it?

Comment: its a mess getting there.. html code  
<select id="ControlGroupContact_ContactInputView_DropDownListCountry" class="wHuge1s jqTransformHidden" name="ControlGroupContact$ContactInputView$DropDownListCountry"><option value="">Selecione</option>
                    <option value="BR">Brasil</option>
                    <option value="AD">Andorra, Principality of</option>
thats for the options wich is hided